# Creating a self referencing table

Tags: sql-server

I have a hierarchical table - it would suit a self referencing style, like this example I found.

```
CREATE TABLE OurStuff
(
     StuffID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     StuffSubID INT NULL,
     StuffName VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT fk_StuffID FOREIGN KEY (StuffSubID)
        REFERENCES OurStuff(StuffID)
)
```

I have a similar table - however when I try to replicate using Visual Studio Server Explorer, I get an error message:

> "The columns in table 'abc' do not match an existing primary key or
>   unique constraint"

I can understand why, but I don't know why the above which is cited as an example would work and mine does not.

UPDATE: Here the link to the page in the example [“How do I create a self-referencing foreign key?”](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-primary-and-foreign-keys-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/#twelveth)

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: The column you are referencing must me Primary key , In your case `TypeID` must me a Primary key column in `StuffType` table.

Comment: The posted example assumes that there is a table named StuffType, that has a Primary Key or Unique Constraint on the TypeID column.   And by the way, why are you saying that this is an example of self-referencing?

Comment: Sorry - didnt pick that up - then why is it posted as a self referencing foreign key? Or have I misunderstood the term?

Comment: @TabAlleman - Sorry my fault - cut and pasted the wrong example - it is wrong though - posted a linq to the page.

Comment: The example works because the column in the references clause, `OurStuff(StuffID)`, *is* a primary key in a table: `StuffID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: How about posting the actual code that is causing the error instead of posting the example you're trying to copy.

Comment: I am able to run the code you have in your current edit without any error.   There must be something wrong in the way you are implementing it.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli - check out screenshot - its not beyond a chance that I am doing something wrong but I don't see what

Comment: @TabAlleman In my table the Parent column isn't unique as such - many ID's point to the same parent - in the example that is not the case. I'm guessing that is the reason, but is the anyway it can be made to work that way?

Comment: The above isn't the case either - there are 2 elements in the example that aren't unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got the relationship reversed. The `ProductTypeID`column should be on the left under the "Primary key table" and the `ProductTypeParentID` column should be on the right under the "Foreign key table."

Comment: That is definitely the issue.

Comment: You were right Joe, but it didn't work the right way round either - hence I couldn't spot the issue. The reason it didn't work the right way round is because I chose to fill the upmost parent with zero instead of null.